The development server returned response error code:500 (Expo - Android)
I'm working on a ReactNative project with the Expo Android emulator, and right after finishing the backend, I'm getting the following error:
The development server returned response error code:500 (React Native)
url http://192.168.*.*:8081 
node_modules%5expo%5cAppentry.bundle?platform=android%dev=true%hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.router.Root=app

The project repository: https://github.com/maurosergio2112/vacinebem05
I'm trying to solve this error; my project isn't starting on the Expo Android emulator.

Find the logs of your dev server and see what the error is

i'm just beggining now with this, this log is that from terminal? theres apper one menseage: " Android Bundling failed 1794ms (C:\Users\Mauro\vacinebem005\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js)
Unable to resolve "../../App" from "node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js" "

You are calling a server. Go on the machine http://192.168..:8081 and check the http server log u r using there.
A note to you, u do not need to hide IPs that start 192.168 -> those are internal to your network

I managed to solve the problem, it turns out that I had renamed the main App.js file to Index.js, I did the opposite, I renamed it to App.js and it worked.
